# How can I extract the integer (a year) and combination of letters and numbers from each line in a file

Tags: ruby

I am working on a program that reads a file that contains different kind of informations about cellphones, then extracts and stores each piece of information. For example, here are two of many lines from the file:

```
12hrs,Smartphone,2015WB0126A,used,Apple,2000$,{Bluetooth,Water resistant,fingerprint reader,16GB},white,2016
Used,Smartwatch,Samsung,{activity tracker,Bluetooth,water resistant},2017,250$,black,3947t4f,9hrs
```

In the first line above, I want to extract `2016` as the year instead of `2015` and `2000`. And I want to extract `2015WB0126A` as the model (any random combination of letters and numbers) instead of `12hrs` and `2000$`. Can someone help me with this? Thank you very much.

```
f = File.open("listings.txt", "r")
f.each_line do |line|
  puts line
  year=line[/20+[0-9]+[0-9]/]
  puts "made in #{year}"
end
```

For the first line in the example, I expect the year to equal `2016` and the model to be `2015WB0126A`.

Comment: If you already know it's the last 4 chars: `str[-4..-1]`?

Comment: What format is the file in? What program generates it? It looks like a (strange) variation on CSV. Is the model number always the third field? Is the model number always capital letters and numerals, or can it contain other characters? Is the year always the last field?

Comment: The position of the year can be anywhere.  The format and the order can be varied. This is another line from the file: Used,Smartwatch,Samsung,{activity tracker,Bluetooth,water resistant},2017,250$,black,3947t4f,9hrs. The model is always the combination of 'only' letters and numbers. The letters in the model are not always capital letters.

Comment: I can see that the year in your second example line is `2017`, but which part is the model? Is it `3947t4f`?

Comment: Yes, in the second example, '3947t4f' is the model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
f.each_line do |line|
  # find 20xx proceeded by line start or a comma,
  # and followed line end or a comma.
  # ?: makes the group non-capturing
  year = line.match(/(?:^|,)(20\d{2})(?:$|,)/)
  year = year[1] if year

  model = line.split(',').select do |s|
    # 7-30 word characters in length
    s =~ /^\w{7,30}$/ &&
    # at least 5 digits anywhere in the word
    s =~ /(\d.*){5}/
  end

  puts "#{model.first} made in #{year}"
end
```

Hopefully there are some reasonable qualifiers for the model that work with the rest of your data as those are pretty naive.

https://regex101.com/ can give a detailed explanation of any regex if you want more details on exactly how those work. You can use also use https://rubular.com/ to test against ruby's exact flavour of regex.

Answer (score 0):

To handle this, we have to define the patterns first.

from the 2 rows you provided, we know these are info of cellphone. then we can assume:

1. the fields separated by ','
2. the year is in this century, 20xx is a good assumption
3. model is something not human understandable.

```rb
def extract(str)
  fields = str.split(",")
  year = fields.find { |f| f.match /^20\d\d$/}
  model = fields.find do |f|
    f.match /\d/ and f.match /[a-zA-Z]/ and !f.match /\d+(hrs|hr|hour|hours|gb)/i
  end
  return year, model
end
```

in the code I assume the the model contains number and letter. I exclude hours and size(gb) as well. we can also build word list. Cause the info is about cellphone, I guess the list is not long.